# Unit testing JSON ModelBinding in Nancy

Tags: json, nancy, xunit.net

I am trying to test JSON model binding in NancyFx.

The request works when tested in the browser, but I cannot get the unit test to pass.  When I debug the test, I find that the model returned is null from

```
 var model = this.Bind<EventRequestModel>();
```

is always null;

Here is a simplified example of what i'm doing:

NancyModule:

```
    Post["/Events"] = _ =>
    {
        // Convert request to model and validate
        try
        {
            var model = this.Bind<EventRequestModel>();
            var result = this.Validate(model);
            if (!result.IsValid)
                throw  new Exception("Model was not valid");

            return HttpStatusCode.OK
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             _logger.LogError(ex);
             return HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
         }                    
     };
```

Unit Test:

```
    [Fact]
    public void ReturnOkOnGoodRequest()
    {
        // Create a valid model
        var model = new EventRequestModel()
            {
                TopRightLat = 100,
                TopRightLong = 100,
                BottomLeftLat = 100,
                BottomLeftLong = 100
            };

        var response = _browser.Post("/API/Events", with =>
            {
                with.JsonBody(model);
            });

        Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);
     }
```

I have also tried writing JSON directly into the body and doing something like this:

```
    var json = "{'TopRightLat' : 0, 'TopRightLong': 0, 'BottomLeftLat':  0, 'BottomLeftLong': 0}"
    var response = _browser.Post("/API/Events", with =>
        {
            with.Header("Content-Type", "application/json");
            with.Body(json);
         });
```

This JSON body works when I test the endpoint manually but not in my unit test.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason this failed was because I had not added the model binding dependencies to the `ConfigurableBootstrapper` when setting up the test.

This (in the test set up) fixed it

```
_bootstrapper = new ConfigurableBootstrapper(with =>
{
    ...
    with.Dependency<IFluentAdapterFactory>(_fluentValidationFatory);
    with.Dependency<IModelValidatorFactory>(_modelValidatorFactory);
    ...
}
```